# puppeteer - How to click in a new browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Is it possible to do something in a new browser, I don't mean a new page or a new tab, but a new browser that starts after pressing the button.

```
await play[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's a new browser window opened by your code, you can wait for that `target`.

```
const newWindowTarget = browser.waitForTarget(
    target => target.url() === '<The URL you know the browser is going to have>');
await play[1].click();
await newWindowTarget.page.doSomething();
```

Comment: when I don't know what link the next page will have?

Comment: If you call ”new browser” to a new window of the browser you launched using puppeteer, it should work.